# How does Google SMTP work?

Tags: malware, smtp

I am performing malware analysis on a piece of malware which sends emails. The malware contains some hardcoded email addresses. It uses Google SMTP to send emails and I am not sure how it works

Firstly, the malware sends out a DNS request to resolve googles SMTP server IP.
[DNS Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyuJG.png)

Then it initiates 3-way handshake TCP handshake with google's server
[3-way handshake with google SMTP server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHLuj.png)

Then the malware sends an email, but I am not sure how it authenticates with google servers or identifies where to send the email to.
[TCP stream of communication between server and malware](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQCk1.png)

Here is the original pcapng file:[pcap file in wetransfer](https://we.tl/t-AvS8sdX2DX)

My question is how does Google SMTP resolve who to send the email to? And also is it possible to have a fake google SMTP server similiar to fakedns, so that I can receive the email instead?

Comment: SMTP server do not authenticate each other. Therefore if you connect on port 25 and just send an email this will work as long as the address belongs to a user on that server. Some server do not accept incoming SMTP connections from IP ranges known to be used by customer DSL/cable internet connections.

Comment: I see, so if I setup a fake email server on another machine will I be able to receive the email instead?

Comment: If the malware uses plain SMTP without TLS and if you redirect the IP traffic to that server then yes (e.g. using a hosts entry).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Then the malware sends an email, but I am not sure how it authenticates with google servers

It doesn't explicitly authenticate, because it uses the server-to-server "Mail Exchange" port, which is used in this case for delivering mail from *another* domain to Gmail recipients. Mail exchange between domains does not require authentication; email is an open system that anyone can join.

But Google's SMTP server will reject this message as spoofed because it knows that external deliveries of messages claiming to be "from gmail.com" are usually fake (I have several such examples in my Spam folder; they all show the orange spoof warning). Legitimate messages *from* a Gmail user wouldn't be arriving at the MX port – they would be submitted by mail apps via SMTP "Message Submission" ports 465 or 587, which require explicit user authentication with the `AUTH` command.

(And if a legitimate message was forwarded out of Gmail and then forwarded back into Gmail servers via MX, then it would at least have a DKIM signature that Gmail recognizes.)

Also, many domains use SPF to specify which IP addresses are allowed to send mail "from" that domain, which is out-of-band authentication (the server would just reject your `MAIL FROM` command if it failed the check). So if your example claimed to be from a different system (e.g. if it said "From: @yahoo.com"), Gmail would reject the message as failing the SPF checks.

> My question is how does Google SMTP resolve who to send the email to?

The client tells it using the `RCPT TO:` SMTP command, shown in your Wireshark capture.

Together with `MAIL FROM`, the two commands form the message's "envelope" that controls where the message gets delivered (independently from the "From:/To:/Cc:" headers, which are just for display).

> And also is it possible to have a fake google SMTP server similiar to fakedns, so that I can receive the email instead?

Sure, you could either install a real SMTP server and configure it to handle gmail.com as a "local" domain, or write a custom responder that just answers 220/250/354 as needed. (Unfortunately I don't know any existing software for "fake" SMTP servers, but it'd probably be 15 lines of Python/Perl/Ruby to make one from scratch.)